Propagation of MDC to a Feign Thread
I whould need to know how I can propagate the MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) that I use on the main thread to the thread that Feign uses to call another service. I'm using Spring Boot 3.3.0.
This need arises from the requirement to track the flow in a series of logs. Currently, the call to the client, which uses another thread, gets lost among all the other logs.
This is my client and configuration
@FeignClient(
name = "client",
url = "${client.url}",
fallbackFactory = ClientFallbackFactory.class,
configuration = FeignConfig.class
)
public interface Client {
    @GetMapping(value = "${client.path}")
    Optional<String> getObjs(
        @RequestParam("id") Integer id,
        @RequestParam("boolParm") Boolean boolParm,
        @RequestParam("appendix") Integer appendix
    ) throws FallbackErrorException;
}

@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(
        basePackages = {
                "client.package"
        }
)
public class FeignConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomFeignRequestLogging customFeignRequestLogging() 
    {
         return new CustomFeignRequestLogging();
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }

}

[
    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:00", "level": "INFO", "thread": "MainThread", "mdc": {"userID": "12345", "flowID": "abcde"}, "message": "Starting process for user 12345"},
    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:01", "level": "INFO", "thread": "MainThread", "mdc": {"userID": "12345", "flowID": "abcde"}, "message": "Processing data for user 12345"},
    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:02", "level": "INFO", "thread": "MainThread", "mdc": {"userID": "12345", "flowID": "abcde"}, "message": "Preparing to call external service for user 12345"},

    **{"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:03", "level": "INFO", "thread": "FeignThread", "message": "Calling external service"}**,

    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:04", "level": "INFO", "thread": "FeignThread", "mdc": {}, "message": "Received response from external service"},
    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:05", "level": "INFO", "thread": "MainThread", "mdc": {"userID": "12345", "flowID": "abcde"}, "message": "Completed processing for user 12345"},
    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:06", "level": "INFO", "thread": "MainThread", "mdc": {"userID": "67890", "flowID": "fghij"}, "message": "Starting process for user 67890"},
    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:07", "level": "INFO", "thread": "MainThread", "mdc": {"userID": "67890", "flowID": "fghij"}, "message": "Processing data for user 67890"},
    {"timestamp": "2024-07-02T10:00:08", "level": "INFO", "thread": "MainThread", "mdc": {"userID": "67890", "flowID": "fghij"}, "message": "Preparing to call external service for user 67890"}
]

As you can see, until I log inside my services component, I have the MDC, while when I use the client, the MDC object does not exist.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please show your code. The usual, straightforward way is to capture the MDC outside and then apply the MDC inside the lambda. A utility function can help greatly to keep your code organized

Hi @knittl,
I've updated the code. If you need a more specific part of it, please let me know and I'll provide it as quickly as I can. Thanks so much for your help!

@valerioiorio did you find an answer to this?
